# using .each to grab ids from dynamic data in div

Tags: jquery, database, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get the ids of all the `<li>` in the div so I can post to server? This code when fired does nothing except jump the page to the top

```
 $('.showData').on("click", function () {

 $("#AddedItems li").each(function (index, value) {
     var ids = $(this).attr("id");
 });
    alert("ids = " + id);
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an array of all the ids using `map` :

```
var ids = $("#AddedItems li").map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
```

You could also use `each` but it's less convenient and logical :

```
var ids = [];
$("#AddedItems li").each(function(){
    ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Nice, and once I have those ids I can just add them to my post action or is there additional formatting such as serialize involved?

Comment: I don't know how you post (this is a different question) but, supposing you use something like `$.post`, the serialization is done for you by jQuery, you just pass the data as object, for example `$.post('myUrl.php', {some:"argument", ids: ids}, success:function ...`

Comment: I'll ask separately because I need to also figure out how to save all these ids in the db so they can be called down

Comment: follow-up question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426784/storing-multiple-ids-into-one-field-in-db-mvc4